# How to detect rectangles next to each other in Python using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter but am trying to make a program where a rectangle AI will navigate a maze of other rectangles, however I'm not sure what is the best way to detect the rectangles around my AI so it can find openings and figure out where to go (like look left and right to see if there are rectangles)

I tried making collisions but I could not get that to work very well, but I'm also not making each maze wall into it's own variable so I don't know how to check if it's coordinates relate to the AI's. So maybe see if there is anything "AIPossition_x + 5" or something similar?

This is the code I'm using now

```py
maze_create_x = 25
maze_create_y = 25

for char in maze:
    if char == "+":
        canvas.create_rectangle(maze_create_x, maze_create_y, maze_create_x + 25, maze_create_y + 25, fill="black")
    elif char == "/":
        maze_create_y += 25
        maze_create_x = 0
    maze_create_x += 25


robot = canvas.create_rectangle(80, 55, 95, 70, fill="blue")
```

I want the "robot" AI to be able to see if there is a rectangle in front, left, or right of it but I'm not sure where to even start. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `canvas.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)` were (x1, y1, x2, y2) are  the coordinates of rectangle in which you want to know if there are items. The tuple of the ids of the items overlapping this rectangle is returned.

For example, to check on the right of the AI:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(robot)
if canvas.find_overlapping(x1 + 25, y1, x2 + 25, y2):
    print('There is a wall on the right')
else:
    print('The way is clear on the right')
```

Comment: Yes that worked! I was trying to figure out how find_overlapping worked but I couldn't find much, thanks for the help!